# How to write a basic SORT program in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, bubble-sort

I am just starting to learn how to write programs in assembly language. I have come across some ways to write a basic SORT algorithm but they have commands I don't know/am not support to use.

I need to write a program that sorts a series of numbers from least to greatest.

My thought process so far is that I would add Index 0 and 2s complement of Index 1, if the accumulator was positive, branch it so that it then stores Index 0 somewhere else, store Index 1 at Index 0, then take what was at Index 0 previously stored elsewhere and put it at Index 1. Increment the Index until there are more actions done. So basically a bubble sort I guess.

My problem is I don't really understand how the memory addresses, indexing, and such work. I also haven't learned many different ASC Instructions. I think we have learned the basic 16 as my teacher called it.

So I guess, what is the most basic form of bubble sort in assembly language?

For complete clarity here are the 2 questions I am supposed to answer. I figured if I can do the sort I can do the first one.

1. Location #H50 contains an address pointing to the first entry in a table of integers. The table is also in the memory and the first entry is the number of entries in the table, excluding itself. Store the maximum and minimum valued integers at mememory locations MAX and MIN, respectively.
2. SORT the entries in a table of n entries in increasing order of magnitude.

Also, #H50 means ORG 50 right?

Comment: Which chipset are you using (ie which assembly language)? # is immediate (ie an absolute number), H is hex (sometimes $) and 50 is, therefore, the hex number 50. ORG is a macro that tells the assembler where to put the following code, in your example (probably) *decimal* 50.

Comment: We don't write code for you. Ask about what you don't understand.

Comment: I guess what I don't understand and am trying to get a better grasp on is how indexing and memory addresses work. With this assignment being the context in which to explain.

Comment: You should try writing the sort in another language first, like C or whatever language you know. If it's C, you may be able to have the compiler generate assembly code for you, then you can modify or at least read the assembly code to understand it.

Comment: We also don't do your homework for you. Post some code, tell us why/how you think it isn't working (and mention those operators that you are not supposed to use) and then we might help

Answer (score 0):

Without the CPU details, I can only give a generic answer.

Certain registers can be used as indexes. The name of the register and (to a lesser extent) the syntax varies by system. For example, if the x register were the index register and each of the numbers is a single byte:

```
load   x, NUM_OF_INTEGERS ; *size of integer if your addressing mode doesn't compensate
number_loop:
load   r1, H50,x    ; Read byte at 50+x into r1
cmp    r1, H50-1,x  ; Compare with previous value
bcs    bigger       ; carry set - greater than previous one
    ; Swap H50,x with H50-1,x
    push r1         ; save onto stack (or use a different register if you have one available)
    load r1, H50-1,x; get previous value
    store r1, H50,x ; save it in current position
    pop  r1         ; restore it from stack 
    store r1, H50-1,x ; save it in earlier position
    ; probably want to take note that you've done this somewhere so that you know to do another pass
bigger:
dec    x            ; subtract 1 from index (or 2 or 4 if multi-byte numbers and addressing in your CPU doesn't compensate)
bne    number_loop  ; if index not zero, do it again on the next numbers
```

Hope this helps.